# multisite shared settings

Tags: multisite, options, sync

I'm using multisite installation to separate content by city.
I considered other options, but multisite is the best for me.

But as there will be many sites, which will differ only by content and user roles, I need to sync all wordpress and plugins settings between all sites.

I found a config hack - you can rewrite users table name, so every site will use same users table. So I thinking of something simmilar to overwrite settings table name. But wordpress holds few fields there which should not be the same: siteurl, home, blogname, blogdescription. Maybe something else. 
Also there is no hooks to replace settings table name, so I would need to edit wordpress code and that would extreme measures.

Moreover it would be much better to store all settings in a file so it will be stored in version controll.

Is there any solutions? I know there's not many people who use multisite installation, but maybe someone have any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Update from comments

To convert an array of options to site options, you can try something like this:

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpse245699_use_site_options' );
function wpse245699_use_site_options() {
    // Uses site options for these options.
    $required_site_options = array(
        'some_option_name',
        'another_option_name',
        'and_another_one',
    );
    foreach( $required_site_options as $option ) {
        add_action( 'update_option_' . $option, 'wpse245699_update_site_option', 10, 3 );
        add_filter( 'pre_option_' . $option, 'wpse245699_get_site_option', 10, 2 );
    }
}

function wpse245699_update_site_option( $old_value, $value, $option ) {
    update_site_option( $option, $value );
}

function wpse245699_get_site_option( $pre_option = false, $option ) {
    return get_site_option( $option );
}
```

This code is *untested*.

I wouldn't recommend converting all of WordPress's options to site options; there are a number of core options in use on every site, and setting them all to identical values would most likely end badly.

---

WordPress Multisite uses one table for all its users already; you shouldn't need any kind of "config hack" to accomplish this. As for plugins and settings: you can Network Activate plugins and they'll run on every site in your Multisite network. And settings (or options -- I assume you're referring to the data stored by the [Options API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Options_API)) can be stored and retrieved on a per-site basis (using the `*_option()` functions) or globally across the network (using the `*_site_option()` functions).

WordPress stores virtually all its data in the database, so saving and loading options/settings from a file isn't really The WordPress Way.

### References

- [Multisite Network Administration](https://codex.wordpress.org/Multisite_Network_Administration)
- [Options API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Options_API)

Comment: _site_options sounds interesting. It would be exact thing I need if only problem was in my own plugin. But I need all plugins I use to store their settings globally. So if only I could hook somewhere and use _site_option inside every _option used by other plugins...

Comment: I see there is a nice filter for update_option: 
$value = apply_filters( 'pre_update_option', $value, $option, $old_value );

Which supplies option name and I can use to set option globally.

But get_option does not use common filter and uses different one for each option name^
$pre = apply_filters( 'pre_option_' . $option, false, $option );

Is there a way to add filter with prefix and get filter name inside my hook? Something like:
add_filter('pre_option_*', 'custom_get_option', 10, 3);

Comment: I've updated my answer. Also, be aware that WordPress uses a bunch of core options on each site, so changing every single option in a site to use a network-level option probably will not work well.